# Get domain name from url without www / http but include tld

Tags: php

I need to get a domain and tld from a string.

I've tried:

```
parse_url('https://www.google.com', PHP_URL_HOST);
```

But `www` still remains.

Is there a way to do this without knowing all of the tlds that are in existence?

```
subdomain.example.com
https://example.com
http://www.example.com
example.com
www.example.com
www.example.co.uk
```

All of the above should produce `example.com` or `example.co.uk`

Note, im not trying to get the TLD only, I want the domain and TLD together.

Comment: @Mureinik no, I want the domain as well as the tld, e.g. `example.net` not just `.net`

Comment: @panthro Look more carefully at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39515132/157957): `getRegistrableDomain` in the library listed seems to do exactly what you want (and if it didn't, finding the ".co.uk" is the hard part, finding the token before that is easy).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this without knowing all of the tlds that are in existence?

Unfortunately, no.

As far as the domain name system is concerned, the TLD of all of the following is is ".uk":

- [www.example.co.uk](http://www.example.co.uk)
- example.co.uk
- nhs.uk
- login.mydoctor.nhs.uk
- a.w.e.s.o.m.e.uk

The only way to look at "www.example.co.uk" and decide you want the output "example.co.uk" is to apply one of two pieces of knowledge:

- Common *prefixes*, such as "www.", which you want to strip off
- Common *suffixes*, such as ".co.uk", which you want to treat as "almost TLD"

For the latter, there is [a database maintained by Mozilla of "public suffixes"](https://publicsuffix.org/). It is used for instance for determining the scope of cookies.

Comment: Thank you - so basically what you are saying, it's not that simple with string manipulation, you need that TLD list to do it properly.